# Razor syntax for boolean check

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have the following Razor syntax in an Asp.Net Core application:

```
if (!@string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.BasketId) && $('#product-code').val().length !== 0) {
```

However, I get the following Javascript error:

```
ReferenceError: True is not defined
```

If I look at the JS in the debug section, the line is resolving as:

```
if (!True && ...
```

Which is clearly not correct Javascript. So how do I perform a check like this is Razor, such that it resolves to valid JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lower case the string:

```
if (!@string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.BasketId).ToLower() && $('#product-code').val().length !== 0) {
```

Comment: I did consider this, but it seemed such a bizarre solution, I assumed there must be a better way

Comment: @stannage, as c# and JavaScript are different language you have to consider this:)

Answer (score 0):

It is almost valid js, if it wasn't for the capital T

You have several ways of solving this:

ToString with ToLower will result in lowercase `true`

```
if (!@string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.BasketId).ToString().ToLower() && $('#product-code').val().length !== 0) {
```

You could also do a ternary if statement

```
if (!@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.BasketId)?1:0) && $('#product-code').val().length !== 0) {
```

Returning 1 or 0 would also result in truthy or falsy value in js

Comment: I like this, but unfortunately, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.BasketId)?1:0 resolves to "True ? 1 : 0" which is still invalid

Comment: @stannage did you add the () brackets around the statement like I did?

Comment: Yes, it made no difference

Comment: @stannage I don't know why, I tried with `if (!@(true?1:0)) {` and it resulted in `if (!1) {` and that code should be basically the same. Could you paste exactly how you tried to apply the code?

Answer (score -1):

You are combining C# & JavaScript together in one line. Try below:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.BasketId))
{
    <script>
        if ($('#product-code').val().length !== 0)
        {
            /* Put your logic here */
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: It works, but this kind of solution will be very hard to handle with bigger code. I only recommend for short codes.